# Процедура и событие mysql

Tags: mysql

Создаю тестовые процедуру.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Daily_Insertion1()

BEGIN
    insert into deliverability.test_month (type,from_sale)
    select type,from_sale
    from deliverability.delivery_money_repo
    where total = 289001;
END
```

И ивент

```
CREATE EVENT myevent1
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2017-02-22 11:14:00'
    DO
      CALL Daily_Insertion1
```

Устанавливал ближайшее время, чтобы проверить работоспособность. Не сработало, что сделал не так?

Comment: Как определил, что "не сработало"? Думаю, эвент выполнен, процедура запущена, но в процессе выполнения либо ошибка, либо пустой набор записей, потому в целевую таблицу ничего и не упало.

Comment: @Akina Сам запрос, без процедуры, корректно вставляет данные. В указанное время ничего не добавилось в таблицу, после предполагаемого действия процедуры/ивента.

Comment: Проверяйте тогда по логу, запускался эвент или нет. Ну и на всякий случай проверьте, а запущен ли вообще event sheduler...